# Why try block only is not allowed?

Tags: java, kotlin, try-catch

Why in Kotlin (also in Java except the case of try-with-resources) it is not possiable to write a try{} block only ? for example:

this function is allowed

```
fun tryFunction(){
    try{print("hello world!")}finally {}
}
```

while this one is not allowed

```
fun tryFunction(){
    try{print("hello world!")} //build error "Expecting 'catch' or 'finally'"
}
```

in spite of finally{} block at the first example does nothing

Comment: What would happen then if the `try` failed?

Comment: the same what would happens if there is an empty finally block ... nothing

Comment: "try/catch", "try/catch/finally" and "try/finally" mean "try to do something, if if that fails do...", "Try to do something, if that fails do ... and afterwards do ....", and "try to do something, and afterwards do ...." respectively. Try by itself just means "try to do something" - and isn't that the point of all code without a try? So, why do you need a try for that?

Comment: try block alone could have potentially one of the following use:

1. in case of exception resume next block of code silently as if you write : 
`try{...//code that throw exception}catch(e:Exception){ //do nothing}`

2. automatically invoke close() to all the object that implement Closeable and created within that try block without need to but them inside parentheses

Comment: Implicit things happening behind your back is not what Kotlin is about.

Answer (score 5):

"try/catch", "try/catch/finally" and "try/finally" mean

- "try to do something, if if that fails do..."
- "try to do something, if that fails do ... and afterwards do ...."
- "try to do something, and afterwards do ...." respectively.

Try by itself just means "try to do something" - and it is implicit in all code that is what you want to try to do; so you don't need any extra cruft like a `try` to express that.

If you simply want to have the statements in their own block, for example to scope variables to that block, you can always omit the `try`.

In terms of your question of why an empty `finally` block is allowed: it is simply that `finally` should be followed by a block, and it is valid for a block to have no statements. It is sufficiently rare that you should want to have an empty finally block that it is not worth making it a special "non-empty block" syntax element.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "Because that's the way the language was defined".

Sure, they could have decided a naked `try { ... }` had an assumed empty `finally`, but then that's equivalent to not having the `try` at all, so why bother?

Comment: 1. Because its an build error not just a warning. 
2. It could have been mean something useful.
maybe a good answer would be language designer reserve it for something in the future

Comment: You'd have to ask the language developers.